# Could you please correct the code is_admin()

Tags: functions, allowedtags

I have this code in my function.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() { 
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://madeeasy-online.com/zhile-2/dobavit-obyavlenie/', 302);
        exit;
    }
}
```

But I want 'moderator' to reach the admin-panel. What should I add to the code?

Thank in advance, Sv

Answer (score 0):

What is a moderator? A custom user role? If yes, then:

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() { 
    if ( is_admin() && (!current_user_can( 'administrator' ) || !current_user_can( 'moderator' ) ) && ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://madeeasy-online.com/zhile-2/dobavit-obyavlenie/', 302);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is, 'moderator' is custom user role. Unfortunately, it does not work, the code is correct but 'moderator' cannot reach the admin-panel only front-end. I tried with 'editor', the result is the same :(((

Thank you very much for attempt!

Sv.

Comment: What if you try a common capability between the two roles like current_user_can('edit_others_posts')